# Task status and timesheet issue

Tags: project-server

We have SP 2010 farm together with Project Server and client computers with Win 7 & 64-bit Project prof. 2010 client app. inside. Strange thing, task names and time sheets completely disappears from time to time, without error message, items in event log or so on.

Suprisingly, we found this KB intended for Project client application
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2584056

... and as someone told us, as long as there is at least one computer with non-patched application, task lists are in danger. My question is - Can we do something on server side to fix this issue?

Can this fix really help us? Because client stations with Project app. are many and if it does not to be solved on server side, we need to disable access for clients without patch almost immediately. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we applied mentioned patch to users computers and set reject conditions for all non-patched MS Project clients (Server Settings / Additional Server Settings, Project Professional Versions section), that means deny for all version smaller than 14.0.6112.5000.

When user with incorrect version of MS Project try to connect our Project Server, following error message will comes up

[image]

... and must ask his/her local Service Desk for help.

P. S. You need to install MS Project SP1 before the patch first.